# How can we test the alert and the text it is displaying using Cypress.io Js automation framework?

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can we test the alert and text inside is displaying using Cypress.io Js automation framework? I am unable to figure out the relevant example in Cypress documentation, please advise.

```
describe('Test an alert and the text displaying', function() {
it('Verify alert and its text content', function(){
    cy.visit('http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/javascript-alert-box-demo.html')     
    cy.get('button').contains('Click me!').click()
    cy.on ('window:alert', 'I am an alert box!')    

    })

})
```

Comment: Maybe `cy.on('window:alert', stub)` from [this example](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Window-Alert)

Comment: @Richard Matsen: Awesome, figured out !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Figured out the answer using cy.stub() method as advised by Richard Matsen:

```
describe('Test an alert and the text displaying', function() {
it('Verify alert and its text content', function(){
    cy.visit('http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/javascript-alert-box-demo.html')    

    const stub = cy.stub()  
    cy.on ('window:alert', stub)
    cy
    .get('button').contains('Click me!').click()
    .then(() => {
      expect(stub.getCall(0)).to.be.calledWith('I am an alert box!')      
    })  

    })

})
```

Answer (score 23):

This is a much simpler and more intuitive way:

```
cy.on('window:alert', (str) => {
  expect(str).to.equal(`This is an alert box!`)
})
```

I've found the `stub()` method of doing this to be way too messy, unintuitive and error-prone.

Comment: However, does this fail the tests if no alert box is ever shown? I doubt so.

Comment: Indeed, this test will fail to reveal the absence of the `'window:alert'` event, so it is not correct.

Comment: I'm sad never saw this comment and didn't reply sooner. But that should be a separate test. Test that the alert is shown, then test that it shows the correct message. Simpler, more readable.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get the accepted answer using `.stub()` to work, despite it being official Cypress solution for `alert`. Apparently I'm not alone here so I thought I'd share my workaround in case it helps someone in the same boat.

Expanding on @codemon's answer, this workaround *will* fail the test if no alert was fired:

```
   var alerted = false;
   cy.on('window:alert', msg => alerted = msg);

   cy.get('button').contains('Click me!').click() //or whatever code that triggers alert
   .then( () => expect(alerted).to.match(/clicked!/); //or whatever regex is appropriate
```

Comment: Thanks. I had trouble using stubs also and this works for me.

I believe there's an error in your code, though. I think the last line needs to start with:

.then(() => expect...

Answer (score 2):

Cypress docs now advise to set an alias to the stub. This works fine:

```
// Give an alias to the stub, so we can use "get" on it.
const alertShown = cy.stub().as("alertShown")

cy.on ('window:alert', alertShown)

cy.contains("button", "Click Me").click()

// By using get, we ensure this will be retried if the checkbox has 
// not been called yet.
cy.get("@alertShown").should("have.been.calledOnceWith", "I am an alert box!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using this: [alert.js](https://github.com/PaulNieuwelaar/alertjs), then maybe I can save you some headache.  Try something like this to find the element that is NOT registered with the DOM:

```
// for example, a button in the modal that needs clicking

// the event that fires the alert
 cy.get('<some element>').click()

 cy.window().then(win => {
        const el = win.Alert.$(`<whatever element you're looking for>`)
        cy.wrap(el)
          .find('button')
          .contains('Confirm')
          .click()
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Catalog of events available to cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#App-Events):

> window:alert
>
> Yields:   the alert text (String)
>
> Fires when your app calls the global window.alert() method. Cypress will auto accept alerts. You cannot change this behavior.

> window:confirm
>
> Yields:   the confirmation text (String)
>
> Fires when your app calls the global window.confirm() method. Cypress will auto accept confirmations. Return false from this event and the confirmation will be canceled.

```
//to validate the alert box string
cy.on('window:alert', (str) => {
  expect(str).to.equal('Please fill out Username and Password.')
})
cy.log('The alert is having the expected text')
//to click the 'ok' button in the alert box 
cy.on('window:confirm', () => true);
cy.log('The alert is having the "ok" button')
```