# How to capture and display text for auto appearing and disappearing pop-up using cypress

Tags: cypress, alert

i Would like to know the method on How to capture and display text for auto appearing and disappearing pop-up using cypress.
I had used the window methods for capturing the text and displaying it, but it doesn't capture the message.

The pop-up/alert is designed to appear whenever user generates a report and it automatically disappears after 3 secs.

Please help

Comment: Please add your code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what creates the popup.

For window alert, this question [How can we test the alert and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795306/how-can-we-test-the-alert-and-text-inside-is-displaying-using-cypress-io-js-auto) uses stub to capture the call.

It asserts the stub is called with certain text.

```js
const stub = cy.stub()  
cy.on ('window:alert', stub)
cy.get('button').contains('Generate Report').click()
  .then(() => {
    expect(stub).to.be.calledWith('I am an alert box!')      
  })
```

From [Cypress Window-Alert](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Window-Alert)

---

If the popup is generated by framework, e.g React the approach is the same as any text on the page.

You might need to use `cy.clock()` to control the timing, presuming you want to assert the appear/disappear cycle.